# Select date on which an employee hasn't entered his/her log

Tags: mysql

I have a system where employees enter their daily log details.

I want a mysql query which gives report of one week and also returns null if someone havent entered their log.

Here is what I have tried.

```
select employee_log.*,employee.* from employee_log
left join employee on (employee_log.employee_id = employee.id)
group by employee.id
```

But it only returns the data when the employee has entered their log. But I also want to show if any employee has not entered their log on the particular day.

Comment: I think you might want to check this in your application itself, since it is quite complicated logic and would otherwise require a stored procedure.

Comment: Check this: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/. I think you need a `left outer join`

Comment: How is the system meant to know on which days it's *meant* to have logs for employees? (I'm assuming they're not all meant to work every day of the week, including weekends)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever they are working from monday to saturday, so I just want to check wether any employee havent inserted his/her log for particular day... `I have two tables , one is employee and another is employee_log` and `employee_log has a foreign key from employee table`..

Comment: @Sal00m i have read about joins.. but `full join` is not supported by mysql...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
select * from employee
left join employee_log on (employee.id = employee_log.employee_id)
group by employee.id
```

You want to get all details of employees they are log or not log so use left join like this `employee   left join employee_log`

Answer (score 1):

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), 
>   with the matching rows in the right table (table2).  The result is
>   NULL in the right side when there is no match.

As you have written your SQL statement you need to swap employee_log with employee since currently your returning all rows from employee_log.

```
select employee_log.*,employee.* from employee
left join employee_log on (employee_log.employee_id = employee.id)
group by employee.id
```

Comment: Thanks may.. this worked. but as SATSON has also given the same answer before you so i have to accept his answer. but will sure +1 yours.. :-)

Comment: True... though he didn't link it to the theory (though not difficult at all) . "Give a man a fish, he will eat for a day. Teach a man to fish and he will eat for a lifetime". :)